# OWA could not read setting from server. The destination is unreachable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-farm, owa

I get an error

> Could not read setting from server. The destination is unreachable

While running the following cmdlet.

```
New-OfficeWebAppsMachine -machineToJoin ServerH
```

The OWA farm works fine with the OWA server G.

```
Current Configuration
 2 Frontend servers Server A & Server B
 2 App servers Server C & Server D
 2 Distributed Cache servers Server E & Server F
 2 Office Web App servers Server G & Server H
```

I have checked there is no proxy settings in IE.

Comment: Are you specifying `ServerH` with fully qualified domain name (e.g. `serverh.company.com`)?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you moe for responding.

I was able to connect ServerH to the OWA farm.  I used the same cmdlet but replaced server by server which is the parent OWA server.

```
New-OfficeWebAppsMachine -MachineToJoin ServerG
```

This [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_web_apps_server_2013_support_blog/archive/2013/12/20/office-web-apps-2013-rebuild-your-farm-in-a-few-easy-steps.aspx) explicitly states the  fix .